# How to quote dollar sign in variable through `sudo -s`

Tags: escaping, sh, sudo

If I have a script subtest.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh

echo "subtest arguments: $@"

variable=${1?"You must provide variable!"}
echo "$variable"
```

…which is called via a script test.sh:

```
#! /bin/sh

echo "test arguments: $@"

variable=$1
sudo -u $USER -s ./subtest.sh "$variable"
```

This works as expected for most input strings. For example:

```
$ ./test.sh 'abc def'
test arguments: abc def
subtest arguments: abc def
abc def
```

However, when the input string has a dollar sign in it, it breaks!

```
$ ./test.sh 'abc$def'
test arguments: abc$def
subtest arguments: abc
abc
```

How can I properly quote my variable so that it always appears unaltered on the other side?

I've tried all sorts of tricks (e.g. `"'$variable'"`, `$(printf '%q' "$variable")` but if I set `SHELL=echo` I can see them all get thwarted: the quotes themselves get escaped, such that the `$` in the user input always ends up interpreted by the shell!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this has nothing to do any usual shell variable handling suspect. Instead, it turns out this is all but intentional on the part of `sudo` itself!

In a mirror of its [parse_args.c:566](https://bitbucket.org/millert/sudo/src/38ea56670f1878fd1b6d474d6f9a512326ae8d97/src/parse_args.c?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#parse_args.c-566) one finds this logic:

```
/* quote potential meta characters */
if (!isalnum((unsigned char)*src) && *src != '_' && *src != '-' && *src != '$')
        *dst++ = '\\';
```

The dollar sign is explicitly whitelisted, and *won't* be escaped! But all the things I would do to escape the dollar sign do *themselves* get escaped….

As far as I can tell the only way around this is to avoid triggering the `-s` mode. It works with plain `sudo -u $USER ./subtest.sh "$variable"`, so now I'm trying to remember why I [thought I?] needed the `-s` in the first place :-/